# jQuery - change background image if hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, background-image

I have a jQuery code that works perfect when you hover on the div.

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#div-to-hover').hover(function(){
        jQuery('#my-background-image').css("background-image", "url(active.png)");
    });
});
```

I want to change it so that when it is hovered, then active.png is the background-image. If not hovered, then it becomes normal.png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#div-to-hover').hover(function(){
        jQuery('#my-background-image').css("background-image", "url(active.png)");
    }, function(){
        jQuery('#my-background-image').css("background-image", "url(normal.png)");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just inspect the event type to see if the hover event is a mouseover or mouseout event.

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#div-to-hover').hover(function(e){
        var path = (e.type == 'mouseover') ? 'active.png' : 'normal.png';
        jQuery('#my-background-image').css("background-image", "url("+path+")");
    });
});
```

Comment: or you could use the other half of the hover function whichn does this for you.

Comment: @JonTaylor: +1 to that! I prefer this way tho :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely it would be better to set the div to always have background of `normal.png` and just use your current code, rather than add even more jQuery?

Comment: yes but his current code does nto remove and reset the background to normal on mouseout.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The background becomes active and never changes back. That's why I asked this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in pure CSS.

```css
#my-background-image {
  background-image: url(normal.png);
} 

#div-to-hover:hover #my-background-image {
  background-image: url(active.png);      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyzzy/fjh5z/

Comment: This is true, however youre making the assumption `#my-background-image` is nested within `#div-to-hover`

Answer (score 0):

Complete example and source: http://jsfiddle.net/maho/6swag/

Don't use javascript to style elements directly inline. Use classes instead.
That way you can use seperate CSS to style it, which is far better.